# Lambda GroupBy por ano e mês

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, linq

tenho uma lista de eventos, e gostaria de agrupá-las por ano e mês,
por exemplo

**[Ano 2017]** 
 *Mês Janeiro* 
 { Evento 1, Evento 2, Evento 2 } 
 *Mês Fevereiro* 
 { Evento 3 } 
 
**[Ano 2018]** 
 *Mês Janeiro* 
 { Evento 4, Evento 5 }

estou utilizando Lambda no C#, tenho algo parecido com isso já:

```
var groupLista = listaDeEventos.GroupBy(x => new {x.Data.Year, x.Data.Month})....
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basicamente, existem duas formas de fazer isso.

A maneira complicada, onde é necessário fazer um agrupamento por ano e outro mês, sendo este segundo dentro do primeiro (*ok, nem é tão complicada assim*).

E também a maneira fácil, que seria agrupar diretamente por mês e por ano, juntos, ou seja, concatenar mês de ano de uma maneira que eles sejam chaves únicas para o agrupamento.

Se for necessário manter uma hierarquia (evento -> mês -> ano), use a forma complicada. Caso contrário, não vejo porquê não usar a forma mais simples.

O código no final do post tem um exemplo de cada uma das duas formas.

Também é possível fazer um agrupamento "duplo", da forma que você mostrou na pergunta, só pra ilustrar, ficaria desta forma:

```
var grupo= listaEventos.GroupBy(x => new { x.Data.Year, x.Data.Month }) 
                       .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Itens = g.ToList() });

foreach(var i in grupo1)
{
    WriteLine($"{i.Key.Year} - { i.Key.Month }");

    foreach(var item in i.Itens)
    {
        WriteLine($"\t{item.Nome}");
    }

    WriteLine("\n");
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    internal static void MetodoFacil()
    {
        var grupo1 = listaEventos.GroupBy(c => c.Data.ToString("MM/yyyy"))
                                  .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Itens = g.ToList() });

        foreach(var i in grupo1)
        {
            WriteLine(i.Key);

            foreach(var item in i.Itens)
            {
                WriteLine($"\t{item.Nome}");
            }

            WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }

    internal static void MetodoComplicado()
    {
        var grupo2 = listaEventos.GroupBy(c => c.Data.Year)
                                 .Select(g => new 
                                 { 
                                     Ano = g.Key, 
                                     Meses = g.ToList()
                                              .GroupBy(c => c.Data.ToString("MMMM"))
                                              .Select(grp => new 
                                                             { 
                                                                 Mes = grp.Key, 
                                                                 Eventos = grp.ToList() 
                                                             })
                                 });

        foreach(var i in grupo2)
        {
            WriteLine($"Ano: {i.Ano}");

            foreach(var mes in i.Meses)
            {
                WriteLine($"\tMês: {mes.Mes}");

                foreach(var evento in mes.Eventos)
                {
                    WriteLine($"\t\t{evento.Nome}");
                }

                WriteLine("\n");
            }           
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {           
        MetodoFacil();      
        MetodoComplicado();
    }

    internal static List<Evento> listaEventos = new List<Evento>
    {
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 1", Data = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01) },
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 2", Data = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01) },
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 3", Data = new DateTime(2016, 01, 22) },
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 4", Data = new DateTime(2016, 02, 24) },
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 5", Data = new DateTime(2016, 03, 30) },
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 6", Data = new DateTime(2016, 04, 04) },
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 7", Data = new DateTime(2017, 01, 01) },
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 8", Data = new DateTime(2017, 09, 30) },
        new Evento { Nome = "Evento 9", Data = new DateTime(2018, 05, 12) },
    };
}

public class Evento
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }  
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oLuW1M) **|** [Código no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/tree/master/CSharp/176853)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Tudo vai depender de como e onde vai utilizar, emitindo em um `console application` como forma de entedimento o [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) é assim:

```
var items = listaDeEventos.GroupBy(x => new {x.Data.Year, x.Data.Month}) 
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Key, 
        Eventos = x.Select(a => new
        {
            a.Evento
        })
    })                        
    .ToList();                 

foreach(var item in items)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", item.Key.Year, item.Key.Month);
    foreach(var str in item.Eventos)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", str);
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
}
```

> Saída:

```
2016 / 1
{ Evento = Event1 }
{ Evento = Event2 }
-----------------------------
2016 / 2
{ Evento = Event3 }
{ Evento = Event4 }
-----------------------------
2016 / 3
{ Evento = Event5 }
-----------------------------
```

<sub>O layout fica a sua maneira, mas, dessa forma fica fácil entender como funciona outra coisa como não foi especificado o nome do campo da descrição eu utilize `Evento` gerando a lista de `Eventos`, sendo que esse nome tem que ser o seu da sua consulta.</sub>

Um outra maneira para utilizar seria a criação de [*ViewModel*](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/design-patterns/o-que-e-e-como-utilizar-o-padrao-view-model-em-um-projeto-aspnet-mvc.html) desse novo tipo de dados:

***Classe*** `EventosModelView`

```
public class EventosModelView
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }         
    public string YearAndMonth
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} / {1}", Year, Month);
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<Events> Events { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
IList<EventosModelView> items = listaDeEventos
                .GroupBy(x => new {x.Data.Year, x.Data.Month}) 
                .Select(x => new EventosModelView
                {
                    Year = x.Key.Year,
                    Month = x.Key.Month,
                    Events = x.Select(s => s)
                })                        
                .ToList();                 

foreach(var item in items)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.YearAndMonth);
    foreach (var str in item.Events)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", str.Evento, str.Data);
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
}
```

é a forma melhor de passar informações para a `View`.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Introdução a consultas LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Operações de consulta LINQ básica (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397927.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)
- [Cláusulas Let, Group By e Order By no LINQ](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3692/clausulas-let-group-by-e-order-by-no-linq.aspx)
- [Understanding the LINQ GroupBy Operator in C#](https://blog.udemy.com/linq-group-by/)
- [O que é e como utilizar o padrão View Model em um projeto ASP.NET MVC](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/design-patterns/o-que-e-e-como-utilizar-o-padrao-view-model-em-um-projeto-aspnet-mvc.html)