# Como realizar um Count em várias colunas?

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Gostaria de fazer um `COUNT` utilizando LINQ / LAMBDA, mas estou tendo dificuldades. Podem me ajudar?

A ideia é reproduzir a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT Conta, Tipo, Documento, Nome, COUNT(0) AS Qtde 
FROM TaxaPrecificacao
GROUP BY Conta, Tipo, Documento, Nome
```

Abaixo algumas formas que tentei fazer mas, claro, todas estão erradas.

```
//Funciona mas a coluna do Count não está sendo calculada
var view = TaxaPrecificacao
.Select(
x => new PrecTxContas
{
    Conta = x.Conta,
    Tipo = x.Tipo,
    Documento = x.Documento,
    Nome = x.Nome,
    Qtde = 0
});


//Erro de sintaxe
var view = TaxaPrecificacao
.Select(
x => new PrecTxContas
{
    Conta = x.Conta,
    Tipo = x.Tipo,
    Documento = x.Documento,
    Nome = x.Nome,
    Qtde = x.Count() 
});


/*Sintaxe OK mas não compila The type appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order*/
var view = TaxaPrecificacao
.GroupBy(
x => new PrecTxContas
{
    Conta = x.Conta,
    Tipo = x.Tipo,
    Documento = x.Documento,
    Nome = x.Nome
})
.Select
(
x => new PrecTxContas
{
    Conta = x.Conta,
    Tipo = x.Tipo,
    Documento = x.Documento,
    Nome = x.Nome,
    Qtde = x.Count()
});
```

Comment: É um sistema bem específico mesmo, mas seria o seguinte: Eu tenho uma tabela onde cadastro taxas para as contas. Uma conta pode ter várias taxas cadastradas na mesma tabela, eu gostaria de contar quantas taxas cada conta tem e exibir dessa maneira: Numero da conta, Tipo da Conta, Documento (CPF ou CNPJ), Nome do cliente e a quantidade de taxas. Acreditem, no meu sistema isso faz sentido. Mas o que estou tendo dificuldade é reproduzir isso via LINQ/Lambda. Ajudou a explicação?

Comment: Não, na verdade não explicou nada do que eu pretendia saber. A regra do seu sistema é irrelevante pra questão, mas vamos lá, **o que você quer é fazer uma consulta agrupando por estes quatro campos e obter a quantidade de cada agrupamento?**

Comment: Sim, como no SELECT de cima.

Comment: Uma boa ideia de leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176853/18246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa ter em mente que o `GroupBy` retorna uma estrutura de agrupamento.

Esta estrutura contém todos os dados de determinado agrupamento e também a chave (`Key`) dele. Por exemplo:  se você tem 5 itens cujas chaves de agrupamento são **`Conta = 01`, `Tipo = 1`, `Documento = 2` e `Nome = "Foo"`**, esta estrutura conterá, dentre outras coisas, **todos os dados do respectivo agrupamento** e um membro `Key` que também será uma estrutura com todos os membros do agrupamento, algo como:

```
{ Conta = 1, Tipo = 1, Documento = 2, Nome = "Foo" }
```

Então, após usar o método `GroupBy()`, você pode trabalhar em cima desta estrutura e usar o método `Count()` para retornar a quantidade de elementos de cada agrupamento, ou `Sum()` para somar os valores de alguma propriedade e assim por diante.

O código seria, basicamente, assim:

```
var view = TaxaPrecificacao.GroupBy(t => new { t.Conta, t.Tipo, t.Documento, t.Nome }) 
                           .Select(gp => new
                                   {
                                       Key = gp.Key,
                                       Qtd = gp.Count(),
                                       Itens = gp.ToList()
                                   });
```

O uso seria algo como:

```
foreach(var v in view)
{
    WriteLine(v.Qtd);

    foreach(var item in v.Itens)
    {
        WriteLine(item.Conta);
    }

    WriteLine();
}
```

[Veja um exemplo funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mibk6L)

Código completo do exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var view = TaxaPrecificacao
                     .GroupBy(t => new { t.Conta, t.Tipo, t.Documento, t.Nome }) 
                     .Select(gp => new
                             {
                                 Key = gp.Key,
                                 Qtd = gp.Count(),
                                 Itens = gp.ToList()
                             });

        foreach(var v in view)
        {
            WriteLine(v.Qtd);

            foreach(var item in v.Itens)
            {
                WriteLine($"{item.Conta} - {item.Valor}");
            }
            WriteLine();
        }           
    }

    static List<TaxaPrecificacao> TaxaPrecificacao = new List<TaxaPrecificacao>
    {
        new TaxaPrecificacao { Conta = "001", Tipo = 1, Documento = "A", 
                               Nome = "Tx 1", Valor = 5m },
        new TaxaPrecificacao { Conta = "001", Tipo = 1, Documento = "A", 
                               Nome = "Tx 1", Valor = 10m },
        new TaxaPrecificacao { Conta = "001", Tipo = 1, Documento = "A", 
                               Nome = "Tx 1", Valor = 52m },
        new TaxaPrecificacao { Conta = "002", Tipo = 2, Documento = "B", 
                               Nome = "Tx 2", Valor = 56m },
        new TaxaPrecificacao { Conta = "002", Tipo = 2, Documento = "B", 
                               Nome = "Tx 2", Valor = 59m },
        new TaxaPrecificacao { Conta = "002", Tipo = 2, Documento = "B", 
                               Nome = "Tx 2", Valor = 19m },
    };
}

class TaxaPrecificacao
{
    public string Conta { get; set; }
    public int Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Documento { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: consegui chegar no resultado que eu precisava. Na verdade eu fiz uma modificação no meu terceiro exemplo que postei na pergunta e funcionou. Onde eu estava instanciando 'x => new PrecTxContas {...}' dentro do GroupBy eu removi a tipagem da Classe, ficando apenas 'x => new {... }'. Mas eu entendi como fazer a partir da sua resposta, quando você explica sobre o membro Key ser uma estrutura de todos os agrupamentos. Obrigado.